# xcode "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, c++11

**Probolem**

I am currenly working on a application uing openCV for ios. The step right now is to make a color histogram on iphone 11 pro. openCV is not supported in swift, therefore I am wrapping openCV framework to enable it to ios. When I build the target, the error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support" occurs.

The steps to the occurance of the error is

1.xcode somehow could not recognize IplImage →　occurance of error "expected a type"

2.Added <#opencv2/core/types_c.h> to the file openCVWrapper.h →　Fixed the former error

3.After building the project, the error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support" occurs

**The current Errors**

```
"OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"　//The error i am working on roght now
"'array'file not found"　//It seems like this error will be fixed once the upper error has been fixed
```

**Codes**

**openCVWrapper.h**

```
#ifndef OpenCVWrapper_h
#define OpenCVWrapper_h
#endif /* OpenCVWrapper_h */
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/core/types_c.h>  //added to fix the "expected type" 

@interface OpenCVManager : NSObject
+(void) makeHistgramFromImage:(UIImage*)image;
+ (IplImage *)createIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)uiImage;
@end
```

**openCVWrapper.mm**

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#import <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+(void) makeHistgramFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{

 cv::Mat imageMat;
 UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

 cv::Mat grayMat;
 cv::cvtColor (imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
 image = MatToUIImage(grayMat);

 IplImage *gray = [OpenCVManager createIplImageFromUIImage:image];

 float range[]={0,255};

 float* ranges[]={range};
 int histSize;
 histSize=256;
 CvHistogram* hist;

 hist=cvCreateHist(1,&histSize,CV_HIST_ARRAY,ranges,1);

 cvCalcHist(&gray,hist,0,NULL);

 cvReleaseImage(&gray);
}
+ (IplImage *)createIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)uiImage
{
 CGImageRef imageRef = uiImage.CGImage;
 CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(uiImage.size.width, uiImage.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);

 CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
 iplimage->imageData,
 iplimage->width,
 iplimage->height,
 iplimage->depth,
 iplimage->widthStep,
 colorSpace,
 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

 CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, uiImage.size.width, uiImage.size.height), imageRef);
 CGContextRelease(contextRef);
 CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

 IplImage *outputImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
 cvCvtColor(iplimage, outputImage, CV_RGBA2BGR);

 cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);
 return outputImage;
}
@end
```

**openCV-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import"OpenCVWrapper.h"
```

**opencv2.framework/Headers/core/cvdef.h line 691-705**

```
#ifndef CV_CXX11
# if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1800)
#  define CV_CXX11 1
# endif
#else
# if CV_CXX11 == 0
#  undef CV_CXX11
# endif
#endif
#ifndef CV_CXX11
# error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support" //where the error is occuring
#endif
```

**What I have done**

In

Build Settings →　Basic →　Levels

Changed C++ Language Dialect to C++11

Changed C++ Standard Library to libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

Right now I am implementing openCV4.x to xcode,however according to similar questions it said that I should be using openCV3.x (because C++11 became only available from version 4.x). Therefore i DID once implement openCV3.x to my project however another error occured inside the framework and it seemed like a harder issue to solve therefore I have decided to use openCV4.x and ask this question in stackoverflow

Although I do know that all I havw to do is to enable C++11 to my xcode, however first to all how do I and how do I fux this error? Or was it the former error "Expected a type" pointing IplImage?

I have searched many web pages, many similar questions in stackflow, but never found the best solution for myself and now have been fighting this error for more than 3 days......
Just to note, as you can see, I do not use computer well, so if you have any solution, I would be very pleased if you tell me in very conscientious way.

**Versions I am using**

xcode 11.4
openCV ver4.2.1

Comment: you're using obsolete C stuff, which have been removed from OpenCV 4. Use the C++ api instead! e.g.: IplImage -> Mat,

Comment: thankyou very much! It seems like Mat type can also be used as IplImage since it has been deleted!