# How to convert CMSampleBuffer to OpenCV's Mat instance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, opencv

I am working on an OpenCV project where I am taking input from iPhone native camera as `CMSampleBuffer` now I wanted to create Mat instance that is required in OpenCV for further process

I have found some old post related with it but all are not working in current swift as those are pretty old.

[Raw image data from camera like "645 PRO"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612647/raw-image-data-from-camera-like-645-pro/11795983#11795983)

[How to convert CMSampleBufferRef to IplImage (iOS)](https://answers.opencv.org/question/10586/how-to-convert-cmsamplebufferref-to-iplimage-ios/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert CMSampleBuffer To UIImage.

```
extension CMSampleBuffer {
    func asUIImage()-> UIImage? {
        guard let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) else {
            return nil
        }
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
        return convertToUiImage(ciImage: ciImage)
    }
    
    func convertToUiImage(ciImage: CIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        context.clearCaches()
        guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else {
            return nil
        }
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return image
    }
}
```

Then you can easily convert UIImage to Mat and return UIImage with/without doing something. 
`OpenCVWrapper.h file`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

+ (UIImage *) someOperation : (UIImage *) uiImage;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

`OpenCVWrapper.mm file`

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/Mat.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdint.h>

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+ (UIImage *) someOperation : (UIImage *) uiImage {
    cv::Mat sourceImage;
    UIImageToMat(uiImage, sourceImage);
    // Do whatever you need
    return MatToUIImage(sourceImage);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please specify where to put  `getMatInstance`'method `.cpp` file or the `.mm` file? 

Also what I need to put in the header file, I am pretty new to objective C and C++

Comment: You need to use ```getMatInstance``` in ```.mm``` file.  Read this https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1

Comment: I updated my code. please check it again.

Comment: As per your answer I have updated my code but after doing the same I am getting two errors

1- "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
2- 'array' file not found

there is another relatable question I have found at stackoverflow but 
it seems like they were using some old version's API however I am using the latest one then how come the errors are coming

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008411/xcode-opencv-4-x-requires-enabled-c11-support

do you have any idea ?

Comment: I didn't know about that. Maybe you wrongly integrated openCV into your project. I followed this(https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1) and successfully integrated it without any errors.

Comment: okay no problem, BTW which version you have used in your project, in the above article Yiwei Ni have used 3.2.0 and I am using latest version 4.5.5

Comment: I used the same version(4.5.5). Integrated it 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I have created a new project and integrated the openCV framework as explained in this article [link]
(medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1)

and I am able to print version in console but as I added below line in `.h` file then I am getting then I am getting `expected a type error` at following line

`+ (cv::Mat) getMatInstance : (UIImage *) uiImage;`
Here is the screenshot of the error
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xYnfIvAHMFlNN6cBTCQrWGt1zebpoz8L/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you need ```Mat``` instance outside of OpenCVWrapper.mm class?

Comment: I updated my code again. check it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's partially solved my problem but I wanted to use Mat from my swift class, is it possible?

in simple words
`I need Mat instance outside of OpenCVWrapper.mm`

Comment: As far as I know ```Mat``` is used as a data type of C++.  It's not allowed outside of ```.mm``` file hence ```.mm``` file refered to C++ file. I don't know for which purpose you need it in swift class.

Comment: Can you please answer this question [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168170/how-to-convert-cv-mat-to-objective-c-mat-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know openCV is written in C++ and you will have to interact with it using an Objc++ or an Objc wrapper.
Hence the resources you found are solid and there are many others on working with OpenCV on iOS. A simple swifty wrapper I found online is - https://github.com/Legoless/LegoCV.

There is a full interoperability between Objc/Objc++ and swift and it is fairly easy to implement. See these two resources for more info - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift
https://rderik.com/blog/understanding-objective-c-and-swift-interoperability/