# OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support in Xcode 13.2

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, swift5

I am trying integrating OpenCV - 4.5.3 in my cocoapod project and when I build project I am getting following errors in **cvdef.h** file.

1. OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support
2. ‘array’ file not found

There is a similar question already there but that case is not applicable in my scenario.
[xcode "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008411/xcode-opencv-4-x-requires-enabled-c11-support)

[image]

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-4-x-requires-enabled-c-11-support-in-xcode-13-2/8533

Comment: actually, these two questions are posted by me. I was looking for the solution and don't know which one is the right place so I have posted on both the forms

Comment: @SajalGupta have you found a solution?